# Algorithm for Partial rectangle shape image recognition

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing

I'm looking for a algorithm (pseudocode is ok, or any readable sourcecode, implementation is prob. in Python) to recognise a partial beam/perspective rectangle on a low res image, and give the angle from horizontal. The algoritm should be realtime 30hz fast so pref analytic or convex optimization. And most importantly robust. The beam can be in any orientation and the width can vary, but the angle should be able to be estmated sub degree. Robustness is the priority.

For now lets assume there is at least some beam visible. But in application the beam could be partially occluded.

[image: goal of algorithm]

Here is a sample of some example data with true angle 78.8253 degree (its binary data with noise)

[image: example data with true angle 78.8253 degree]

1. I've tried a gaussian blur, than a treshold, and than OLS in u-v image coordinates. This is a beginning, but not the way to go. The cut-off corners and edges biasses the angle.

[image: Blur and OLS]

Does anyone know of a good robust and fast way to do this? Thanks

edit 1. Hough Transform

Applying a Hough Transform after gausian blur+treshold and averaging the top 5 peaks in the transform. This is a big improvement! but still it seems biassed by the assymetry in the cutoff. Are there any candidates that take this cut-away into account?
[image]

Comment: try the Hough transform

Comment: thanks BartoszKP, this is a big improvement

Comment: Is the question realy too broad? Im specifficaly looking to robustly recognise a partial beam. It must have been done before.

Comment: This site is focused on implementation problems, or possibly problems regarding some particular algorithm. Your question is specific in image processing context, but extremely broad in programming context (as there are probably many possible implementations/algorithms that will solve this task). You've presented the task clearly, hence the upvotes, but it is still off-topic here. You could try this site: [Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/) (however, please do read their help center, because I'm not entirely sure if such questions are on-topic there).

Comment: OK thanks for the explanation and I aggree. But i'm still keeping my hopes up for another usefull hint in the comments:)

Comment: Another idea is to first use edge detection (e.g. Laplace transform), then cut-out some margin from the sides of the image, and then the Hough transform - so it will hopefully catch the angle correctly using only the edges of the beam. Cutting out the margin from the sides of the image is to ignore the results from the edge detection on the part of the beam that intersects with the edge of the image - hope that's clear :)

Comment: And as often - try applying a median filter first, to clear some of the noise.

Comment: Thanks BartoszKP, yes its clear what you mean. I will try the Hough after a Canny and crop. But trusting on edge detection is probably not robust enough with real data.